# Capybara HTML 'number' attribute interaction

Tags: ruby, html, cucumber, capybara

I'm testing a webpage that has two input fields of type `number`. When I hover over a field, two arrows, up and down, appear to increase or decrease the value in the field.

Is there a Capybara script that would click these arrows?

I can use a standard `fill_in` function to change the value, but I would like to automate clicking the arrows to change the value.

Comment: Those arrows are a browser-specific feature. They will render differently, or even not at all, on different browsers/versions. Unless you have explicitly implemented your _own_ arrows, I wouldn't suggest using them as part of the automated tests -- all you're really testing here is the browser itself, not your own code!

Comment: That is something I put back to them but did say I'd look into it.  Thank you for the response.